# Django Queryset ORM issue with string

Tags: ajax, django, orm, django-queryset

I try compare string from AJAX Request with data( name ) at my Database, but my queryset don't working:

```
def create_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        for i in Name.objects.all():
            if i.name != name:
                Name.objects.create(
                    name=name,
                )
                return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Console:

```
In [3]: for e in Name.objects.all()
    ...:     print(e.name)
Michael
Jack
Chris
```

Comparing don't working and name will storing at my DB.

Name should be unique.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your current logic you create new instance for all others  rows except equal to current post name, you can try `get_or_create`

```
def create_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        obj, created = Name.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
        if created:
            return HttpResponse(status=201)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

more details here [get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)